# Using Update Cursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update

I am currently trying to get my update cursor to populate every row in each attribute table for 175 different feature class fields. I have written the script and it is populating the first row but all the next rows are coming out "NULL" (blank).

This is my script

```
import arcpy, csv

geodatabase = "C:\Users\kd16342\TSB_Values_Project\Tool\RasterTool.gdb"
csvfile = "C:\Users\kd16342\TSB_Values_Project\Documents\Scripts\ServicesforMosaic.csv" #change "Ecosystem Services" to "Ecosystem"

fields = ["Ecosystem","Cur_Con","Scale_Efft","Eff_Con","Recover","Typ_of_ser","Services","Eff_on_ser","Dur_s_aff","Reason","Eff_Durat","Unique_ID","Serv_ad_af","Serv_pe_af"] 

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(csvfile, geodatabase, "ServicesforMosaic")

for x in range (9,176):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(geodatabase+"//ServicesforMosaic",fields) as scursor:
        for rw in scursor:
            if rw[11] == str(x):
                with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("C:\Users\kd16342\TSB_Values_Project\Tool\RasterTool.gdb\Unique_ID_"+x,fields) as ucursor:
                    for row in ucursor:
                        row[0] = rw[0]
                        row[1] = rw[1]
                        row[2] = rw[2]
                        row[3] = rw[3]
                        row[4] = rw[4]
                        row[5] = rw[5]
                        row[6] = rw[6]
                        row[7] = rw[7]
                        row[8] = rw[8]
                        row[9] = rw[9]
                        row[10] = rw[10]
                        row[11] = rw[11]
                        row[12] = rw[12]
                        row[13] = rw[13]
                        ucursor.updateRow(row)
                    del cursor, row
```

All helped welcomed!!!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. "...but all the next rows are coming out" Are they coming out blank?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes first row will populate but all the other rows come out  blank NULL

Comment: It's tough to judge what might be the problem the way you have posted your code. Could you clean it up with the Code Sample button? It would also be nice to get a screen shot of your tables.

Comment: Are you running this in the Python window in ArcMap? You don't perhaps have one row selected in the feature class you are trying to update?

Comment: @Cindy selection wouldn't be the cause of this since mapping layers are not being referenced in the script.

Comment: Basically I have 175 feature class files, each of them has hundreds of rows and I need a script that will populate each of these rows from my table. At the moment it will populate the first row but not the rest

Comment: @cindyWilliams nope have arcmap closed so nothing is selected

Comment: Not sure if this is just a copy/paste error, but the way the code is written now you should get an error message at the line 'del cursor, row', since 'cursor' should be undefined (you have defined 'scursor' and 'ucursor').

Comment: Also, it's somewhat amazing that this script runs at all, since all the paths use (potentially) incorrect backslash convention. All paths should have r'C:\...', double backslash, or forward slashes.

Comment: @ phloem She lucked out as her path doesn't contain any escape sequences (`\n`, `\t`, `\f`, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try settings a WHERE clause on your Search Cursor instead. So, something like:

```
for x in range(9, 176):
    query = '"Unique_ID" = {0}'.format(x)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(geodatabase + "/ServicesforMosaic", fields, query) as scursor:
        for rw in scursor:
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("C:/Users/kd16342/TSB_Values_Project/Tool/RasterTool.gdb/Unique_ID_" + str(x), fields) as ucursor:
                for row in ucursor:
                    row[0] = rw[0]
                    row[1] = rw[1]
                    row[2] = rw[2]
                    row[3] = rw[3]
                    row[4] = rw[4]
                    row[5] = rw[5]
                    row[6] = rw[6]
                    row[7] = rw[7]
                    row[8] = rw[8]
                    row[9] = rw[9]
                    row[10] = rw[10]
                    row[11] = rw[11]
                    row[12] = rw[12]
                    row[13] = rw[13]

                    ucursor.updateRow(row)
```

Also, when using the `with` statement you don't need to del the row or cursor. So, you can remove `del cursor, row` from your code.

Comment: Hi there, I tried this but get the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kd16342/TSB_Values_Project/Documents/Scripts/OnlineHELPCursor.py", line 2, in <module>
    query = '"Unique_ID" = {1}'.format(x)
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: it should be `'"Unique_ID" = {0}'.format(x)`